# pgbouncer works even with the wrong password

Tags: pgbouncer

I just realized today that I can connect to my pgbouncer with the wrong password.

I did try without going through port 5432 (directly to postgresql) and I do get a password authentication error, but when I use port 6432 (going through pgbouncer) the connection is successful even with the wrong password.

As for my Pgbouncer configuration, my `userlist.txt` looks like below

```
"db1" "mypass"
"db2" "mypass"
```

Any idea what the problem could be here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change `auth_type` from trust to plain.

I think it's wrong for the default config file to have auth_type set to trust